# Need regular Expression to Match the reverse of a word in a line

Tags: regex

Sample input string: `Regular Expression is really Tough to understand`

User Typed string: `ralugeR Expression si yllear Tough ot understand`

In the above two string, I need to parse the input string and User typed strings -word by word and need to find a match in the user typed string . such that if

1. Regular in input string should matches with ralugeR .
2. is should match with si
3. really should match with yllear
4. to should match with ot

Note : Input string is not constant string , it may vary. 
for example:

Another sample string can be like: `Regex have wasted my time` .

user typed: `xeger have wasted ym emit` .

I am looking for a regular expression to match reverse of the word in a line.but input word is may be changeable .

but the input string will contain any alphabets in both upper and lower case , along with numbers in it .

Comment: regex is not best suited for this job

Comment: How are you going to compare `and` and `dna` where `dna` stands for `Deoxyribonucleic acid`?

Comment: Matching every other word, then in the replacement, use a callback to _reverse_ the word. What language, Perl ?

Comment: I am using Javascript to match the reverse of the word . Yes i was looking for a match in a way like 1) food should match with doof 2) happy with yppah 3) word with drow

Comment: Find `(\w+\W+)(\w+)`, replace `"$1" + reverse($2)`

Comment: can you please suggest a online tool to check for the above solution. most of the tools have only one word to find the pattern . but i need a tool to add both the input and user typed strings

Answer (score 3):

## Foreward

Using regular expressions is not really ideal for this type of work. There are a ton of edge cases that can be encountered here.

## Description

`\b([^\s])([^\s])(?:([^\s])(?:([^\s])(?:([^\s])(?:([^\s])(?:([^\s])(?:([^\s])(?:([^\s]))?)?)?)?)?)?)?\b(?=.*?\n.*?\b((?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:\9)?\8)?\7)?\6)?\5)?\4)?\3)?\2\1)\b)`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Note: to see the image better, right click the image and select view in new window.

## Summary

This regular expression will do the following:

- Assumes the input string is composed of the following two lines delimited by a new line character

  - Input string
  - User created string
- Assumes the words will only have upto 9 characters
- Assumes the smallest word will be 2 characters long, as the `a` spelt backwards is still `a` but isn't really backwards.
- Does not verify or match word location, in otherwords, a word spelt backwards can appear in any word position in the second line.
- Compares the words in the first line to the second line, where the word in the second line must be spelled backwards to match
- Capture Group 0 will get the word from first line
- Capture groups 1-9 will always have the individual letters
- Capture group 10 will get backwards word from the second line

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/zO4yI1/4

**Sample text**

I'm not sure if it `yllear` was misspelt on purpose in your original question, but I added an additional incorrectly spelled `raelly` into the sample

```
Regular Expression is really raelly Tough to understand
ralugeR Expression si yllear Tough ot understand
```

**Sample Matches**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-1]   `R`
2.  [1-2]   `e`
3.  [2-3]   `g`
4.  [3-4]   `u`
5.  [4-5]   `l`
6.  [5-6]   `a`
7.  [6-7]   `r`
10. [56-63] `ralugeR`

MATCH 2
1.  [19-20] `i`
2.  [20-21] `s`
10. [75-77] `si`

MATCH 3
1.  [29-30] `r`
2.  [30-31] `a`
3.  [31-32] `e`
4.  [32-33] `l`
5.  [33-34] `l`
6.  [34-35] `y`
10. [78-84] `yllear`

MATCH 4
1.  [42-43] `t`
2.  [43-44] `o`
10. [91-93] `ot`
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\s]                    any character except: whitespace (\n,
                             \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\s]                    any character except: whitespace (\n,
                             \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \3:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^\s]                    any character except: whitespace (\n,
                               \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (                        group and capture to \4:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [^\s]                    any character except: whitespace
                                 (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of \4
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                               (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        (                        group and capture to \5:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          [^\s]                    any character except: whitespace
                                   (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        )                        end of \5
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                                 (matching the most amount
                                 possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          (                        group and capture to \6:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
            [^\s]                    any character except: whitespace
                                     (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          )                        end of \6
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          (?:                      group, but do not capture
                                   (optional (matching the most
                                   amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
            (                        group and capture to \7:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
              [^\s]                    any character except:
                                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f,
                                       and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
            )                        end of \7
----------------------------------------------------------------------
            (?:                      group, but do not capture
                                     (optional (matching the most
                                     amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
              (                        group and capture to \8:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                [^\s]                    any character except:
                                         whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f,
                                         and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
              )                        end of \8
----------------------------------------------------------------------
              (?:                      group, but do not capture
                                       (optional (matching the most
                                       amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                (                        group and capture to \9:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                  [^\s                     any character except:
                  ]                        whitespace (\n, \r, \t,
                                           \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                )                        end of \9
----------------------------------------------------------------------
              )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
            )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \n                       '\n' (newline)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \10:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                               (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                                 (matching the most amount
                                 possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          (?:                      group, but do not capture
                                   (optional (matching the most
                                   amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
            (?:                      group, but do not capture
                                     (optional (matching the most
                                     amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
              (?:                      group, but do not capture
                                       (optional (matching the most
                                       amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                (?:                      group, but do not capture
                                         (optional (matching the most
                                         amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                  (?:                      group, but do not capture
                                           (optional (matching the
                                           most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                    \9                       what was matched by
                                             capture \9
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                  )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                  \8                       what was matched by
                                           capture \8
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                \7                       what was matched by capture
                                         \7
----------------------------------------------------------------------
              )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
              \6                       what was matched by capture \6
----------------------------------------------------------------------
            )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
            \5                       what was matched by capture \5
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          \4                       what was matched by capture \4
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        \3                       what was matched by capture \3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \2                       what was matched by capture \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \1                       what was matched by capture \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \10
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```